# subprocess.check_output exit status 2 by pytest command

Tags: python, subprocess

Can anyone help me out with the issue I have? I need to create a script in python to collect all testcase from pytest under path. I tried to use subprocess.check_output but error return as exit status 2. I have tried to use different cmd to check my path and ls. they are all correct

```
cmd = 'pwd'
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
=>'/Users/aaaa/test_project'

cmd = 'ls'
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
=>'pytest.ini\nscripts\npytest_collector.py'

cmd = 'pytest --collect-only'
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
=>{CalledProcessError}Command 'pytest --collect-only' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#possible-exit-codes Says 'interrupted by user' for RC 2. Anything of interest in output.output (and output.stderr if it's python3)?

Comment: And also, https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code may be of interest. pytest.main(['--collect-only']) for example.

Comment: how can I get output.output? it just return exception with non-zero exit status 2.

Comment: Actually, perform check_output in a try-except block, and catch the CalledProcessError.

Comment: hm..it turns out there is **E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'** but i hav eno problem when executing test...does it mean I need to setup python path under subprocess?

Comment: The exitcode 2 is misleading, you can get it for cases other than 'interrupted by user'. See
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4603
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2950
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2832